# Смысл фразы "не сломить ее семи печатей"

Tags: значение-слов, литература

Что автор подразумевал под словами *"нам не сломить ее **семи печатей**"?*

`О да, конечно, до самой луны!
Не трогайте далекой старины.
Нам не сломить ее семи печатей.
А то, что духом времени зовут,
Есть дух профессоров и их понятий,
Который эти господа некстати
За истинную древность выдают.`

И.Гёте, "Фауст"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Существует фразеологизм ***тайна за семью печатями***, о его происхождении можно почитать, к примеру, здесь (приведены самые разнообразные источники и суждения на эту тему):

[Почему говорят - "Тайна за семью печатями"? Кто их поставил, эти печати? | Ответы Mail.Ru](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/23684066)

В данном случае автор имел в виду, что древняя история — это тайна, в ней  нет абсолютного знания, а ученые  в своих книгах рассматривают только различные версии исторических событий.